# FLV video shows wrong playhead time

Tags: apache-flex, flv, red5

I am recording FLV videos with Red5 server and playing them back in a Flex app.  I am aware that Red5 does not properly inject the FLV MetaData, so I am using an external commandline tool to get the metadata in there.

Because I am injecting the metadata, my duration of the video is correct.

The problem I am having, and this is true with all FLV players I try to play the video with (even 3rd party stand-alone video players), is the PlayHead time is never started at 0.  When I load up the FLV to play and lets say the video is 10 seconds long, the current time label on the playhead starts at 1-2seconds instead of 0 and the horizontal slider current time indicator also is moved away from 0 and is set to 1-2 seconds along the slidebar.  *the video plays back fine from what I can see though*.

Is there a byte in the FLV that I need to change so that it will start the playhead at 0?  I realize this is probably something to do with Red5, so if anyone has any work-arounds or potential things to watch out for that may be causing this, I would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Just to update this in case someone else encounters this, it turned out that the version of Red5 I was using (0.9 I believe) was the issue.  I upgraded to 1.0RC1 and immediately the video timeline was corrected to 0.00 - 10.00 (assuming it was a 10 second video).

I was afraid to upgrade to 1.0RC1 because I feared the java app I created would encounter issues with the upgrade since I developed it on an earlier version and read so many posts about things not working with upgrading.. but I guess I got lucky, it works perfectly!